# I'm unable to verify matching between two variables

Tags: jmeter

I'm running HTTP request and sending status values to update.

Request successfully updated value in DB. Now I'm trying match input value vs saved in database value.

I'm using below code to match both values,
[image]

I'm printing logs seems both are same but not matching.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would try to compare it directly without getting the second argument from `vars`:

```
if (updatestatusvalue.equals(apptstatustoday))
```

or explicitly convert strings:

```
if (updatestatusvalue.toString().equals(apptstatustoday.toString()))
```

[As per documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) `vars.get(...)` will convert value to string and if you have non String objects and can affect comparison.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)
2. [JMeterVariables.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String)) returns an [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), it might be the case they of different types, you can check it by calling [.getClass().getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) and seeing what it returns.
3. In Groovy you can use [`==` operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_relational_operators) for comparing objects

I would recommend to convert the objects into [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), this way comparison should work as you expect

Something like:

```
def appstatustoday = vars.getObject('status_value_1') as String
def updatedstatusvalue = vars.getObject('status') as String

if (appstatustoday.trim() == updatedstatusvalue.trim()) {
    log.info('status is matched')
    //etc

}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, converting to string is also working. Thanks once again.